# Pure javascript delete selected rows in html table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to deleted selected or all rows using pure javascript. I am unable to delete selected rows. what was the issue in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfb6p45k/)

Edit: First row is header so not considering that.

```
document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var tableRef = document.getElementById('links-list');
  var tableRows = document.getElementById("links-list").rows;
  var checkedIndexes = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    var checkboxSelected = tableRows[i] && tableRows[i].cells[0].firstChild.checked;
    if (checkboxSelected) {
      checkedIndexes.push(i);
    }
  }

  for (var k = 0; k < checkedIndexes.length; k++) {
    tableRef.deleteRow(checkedIndexes[k]);
  }
});
```

Comment: `tableRows[i].cells[0].firstChild` isn't what you think it is. Additionally, you're ignoring the first row.

Comment: sorry to mention. First row is header.

Comment: The dom is made up of more than just the elements that are represented by html tags. Text between the tags are also nodes within the dom. The first child of the first table cell in each row will be the text node that contains the new line character and tabs/spaces that come between the opening tag and the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `document.querySelectorAll` method with the proper css selector to get all the checkboxes that are checked. Then from the table you can remove those rows with checked checkboxes.

```
let tableRef = document.getElementById('links-list');
let tbody = tableRef.querySelector("tbody");

let checkedInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
Array.prototype.slice.call(checkedInputs)
   .forEach( input => tbody.removeChild(input.parentNode.parentNode))
```

Can also be writen with es7 syntax like this

```
[...checkedInputs].forEach( input => tbody.removeChild(input.parentNode.parentNode))
```

Answer (score 3):

This sould be something like the one below, with `tableRows[i].querySelector('input').checked`, as `.firstChild` is a textnode. Also, index of `tableRows` starts with `0`.

```
document.getElementById('delete').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var tableRef = document.getElementById('links-list');
    var tableRows = document.getElementById('links-list').rows;

    var checkedRows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
        if (tableRows[i].querySelector('input').checked) {
            checkedRows.push(tableRows[i]);
        }
    }

    for (var k = 0; k < checkedRows.length; k++) {
        checkedRows[k].parentNode.removeChild(checkedRows[k]);
    }
});
```

As the last loop alters the dom, deleting based on indexes is not reliable when multiple rows are deleted in the same time. So instead of the pure indexes, it should iterate through the actual nodes.

Comment: `tableRows[i].cells[0].childNodes[1].checked` will also work, but depends on the HTML structure, making a risky solution

Comment: This helped me!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `children` property instead of the `firstChild` one. Also you can enhance your code by avoiding element recalculation. For example, you already found the table, so get the row from it.

Also when you're removing rows, start from the end and go up.

```js
document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var tableRef = document.getElementById('links-list');
  var tableRows = tableRef.rows;
  var checkedIndexes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    var checkboxSelected = tableRows[i].cells[0].children[0].checked;
    if (checkboxSelected) {
      checkedIndexes.push(i);
    }
  }

  for (var k = checkedIndexes.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    tableRef.deleteRow(checkedIndexes[k]);
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="links-list">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type=checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>
      Test1
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type=checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>
      Test2
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type=checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>
      Test3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type=checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>
      Test4
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type=checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>
      Test5
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type=button value="delete" id="delete">
```

Comment: this will not work if you select 1 3 4 and click delete

Comment: Oh, that's because you have another issue. I was focused on your question and didn't pay attention to that. I updated my answer. You need to delete the rows from the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 errors, first you are not getting the value correctly; secondly, you are deleting in the list that you are iterating, so you need to fix that. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("delete").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var tableRef = document.getElementById('links-list');
  var tableRows = document.getElementById("links-list").rows;
  var checkedIndexes = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
    var checkboxSelected = tableRows[i] && tableRows[i].cells[0].firstElementChild.checked;
    if (checkboxSelected) {
      checkedIndexes.push(i);
    }
  }

  for (var k = 0; k < checkedIndexes.length; k++) {
    tableRef.deleteRow(checkedIndexes[k]-k);
  }
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfb6p45k/6/)